# On MAC OS X: how to register a callback to detect physical link UP/Down event?

Tags: macos, operating-system, nic

I'm new to mac os x. I like to have a thread to detect the physical NIC card link
up/down event, not the ip network reachable to the outside.

The old method I got is to using select/timer to do the polling the interface
flags via ioctl...

Anyone has a complete example with API from apple? like register a callback to Kernel and
run forever? If any change (linkup <--> kink down) that will trigger the callback?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested the code with the up/down event but it works for the on/off so it might work. And, I know there's no error handling.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/kern_event.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
   // create a socket of type PF_SYSTEM to listen for events
   int s = socket(PF_SYSTEM, SOCK_RAW, SYSPROTO_EVENT);
   // make sure we get receive the correct events
   kev_request key;
   key.vendor_code = KEV_VENDOR_APPLE;
   key.kev_class = KEV_NETWORK_CLASS;
   key.kev_subclass = KEV_ANY_SUBCLASS;
   //
   int code = ioctl(s, SIOCSKEVFILT, &key);
   kern_event_msg msg;
   // endless loop
   while(1) {
        // get notification
        code = recv(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        // check type of event
        switch(msg.event_code) {
           case KEV_DL_IF_DETACHED:
              // interface is detached
              break;
           case KEV_DL_IF_ATTACHED:
              // interface is attached
              break;
           case KEV_DL_LINK_OFF:
              // interface is turned off
              break;
           case KEV_DL_LINK_ON:
              // interface is turned on
              break;
        }
   }
   return 0;
}
```